# why doesn't listener activate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have the following html:

```
<form id="robokassa" action="//test.robokassa.ru/Index.aspx" method="post">     
    <input type="text" id="OutSum" name="OutSum" value="" placeholder="Сумма пополнения">          
    <input type="button" name="addMoney" value="Пополнить" class="btn">
</form>
```

and following js:

```
$(function () {
    $('#OutSum').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert(2);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("input[name='add-money']").on("click",function(){alert(1);});
});
```

when I click on button - listener doesn't activate.

What do I wrong ?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9wafa6/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `add-money` to `addMoney` in the line `$("input...`. So it should become:

```
$("input[name='addMoney']").on("click", function () {
  alert(1);
});
```

Because you gave your `input` a name of `addMoney` in your HTML but in your JS, you are trying to access an `input` with a name of `add-money`.